# "Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated." after I installed MODX and try to log in to manager panel

Tags: php, modx

"Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated." after I installed MODX and try to log in to manager panel
[image]
[image]

How to solve this problem?
php7.2

Comment: Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php, use a `foreach`

Comment: I am a newbee in writing code on php I have no idea how to improve this thing in MODX without I might broke something)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I read this http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and amended this things. On line 695, file xpdoquery.class.php, string "while (list ($key, $val)= each($conditions)) {" replace with this "foreach ($conditions as $key => $val) {". Second file xpdo.class.php, on line 2845 srting "while (list ($key, $val)= each($this->bindings)) {" replace with "foreach ($this->bindings as $key => $val) {", file xpdoobject.class.php on line 2032 replace "while (list ($key, $val)= each($fldarray)) {" with this "foreach ($fldarray as $key => $val) {" Not sure this's good solution It might help

Answer (score 0):

This should have been fixed as of Revolution 2.6.2

https://github.com/modxcms/xpdo/issues/132
https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/pull/13829